# how to translate variable logical expression to pyspark filter

Tags: python, pyspark, logical-operators

I am looking for a way to transform user input of logical expression into a filter to apply on a data set in pyspark.

eg.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

cSchema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("object_id", StringType()),
        StructField("object_parts", ArrayType(StringType()))
    ]
)

testdata = [
    ['object_1', ["p1", "p2", "p3"]], 
    ['object_2', ["p2", "p4", "p6"]], 
    ['object_3', ["p1", "p3", "p6"]]
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(testdata, schema=cSchema) 
display(df)

object_id | object_parts
------------------------
object_1  |["p1", "p2", "p3"]
object_2  |["p2", "p4", "p6"]
object_3  |["p1", "p3", "p6"]
```

I am now interessted in a way to filter based on logical expression from user input, like

```
filter = "(p1 & p2) | p3"
```

This filter should give lines with object_1 and object_3

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to generalize this for all logical operators and any number of inputs. You'd essentially have to write your own code to parse the input expression and translate it into a spark-sql filter, which is going to be extremely complicated (*especially* if you're using a version older than 2.4). Could this be an [XY Problem](http://www.xyproblem.info)? Are there any other constraints to the inputs (i.e. it will only be AND and OR operators) to help simplify?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not an XY problem, we have a user input with thousands of possible object_parts. For filtering there is an old system with that kind of logic and i want to recreate in a modern system. Thanks for the answer. I used to do it with R dplyr by filtering on all parts of the filter string, added a table with all parts as column with 0 and 1. Then i could apply dplyr::filter_(.dots ...) and replaced filter from filter = "(p1&p2)|p3" --> filter = "(p1==1 & p2 ==1) | p3==1" but that was very ugly and lots of cases to handle.

Comment: Without a lot more details and information about your constraints that could be used to simplify, any solution is going to be *very ugly* with *lots of cases to handle*.